# How to call a python function on an Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, web-applications, https

I have a python function that generates Json files according to the arguments that are passed to it.

We decided to make the argument selection part of a webpage in HTML. After that we want to pass the arguments to the python function on the server. The function generates the specific Json files for the browser to display.

I have looked around and people keep referencing HTTP requests. I'm simply lost on how to call my specific function from this.

I found a simple code that uses HTTP request but I'm lost on what I should change to make it work for mine

```
 <button id="demo" onclick="onClickButton()" type="button">Submit the order!</button> 

<script>
function onClickButton() {
    xhttp.open("GET", "demo_get.asp", true);
```

I'm lost as to what exactly do I pass instead of "demo_get.asp". Like how do I change this code to make it run my the python function on the server

```
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you so much. I know the question is kinda newb.

If you have useful links or tutorials I be will very grateful

Answer (score 0):

After a week of research, I discovered that I had to do the following

I set up the python function using flask and I followed this tutorial to get me started

> http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask

Then instead of using Curl (which what is used in the tutorial)

I used AJAX jquery rather than AJAX since according to this response on stackoverflow. Ajax only allows responses from the same domain. Just search the question "how to call cross-domain web api using ajax?"

I implemented the code in the following manner

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            contentType : "application/json",
            dataType : "json",
            url : "http://localhost:8000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks",
            type: "GET",
            //data : jsonfilename_with_arguments, 
//if you want to post then you have to //change the type to post and send 
//your arguments in a json file
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        alert("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data) + "\nStatus: " + textStatus);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      console.log(textStatus)
    }
        });
})});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div><h2>Hope it works</h2></div>

<button>Display Alarm with content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I changed the url to the IP address of the server and I also changed the port to where my code was running. It is in the following manner

> http://IPAddresss:PORT/todo/api/v1.0/tasks

You might get the following error on the first try when calling another domain

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load IPaddress:Port/todo/api/v1.0/tasks.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

To fix that you can the following code in your server python code to allow Acess-Control (this is how it works with flask)

```
####################Allow Cross Reference########################
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
  response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
  return response
####################Allow Cross Reference########################
```